# Flutter Android SDK manager not found. Не принимаются лицензии андроида на flutter doctor из за этого

Tags: android-studio, flutter, sdk

[image: Flutter Android sdkmanager not found]

Уже 5 раз переустановил Android Studio со всеми SDK, никак не помогает. Перешёл на чуть старую версию тоже не помогло. В SDK Manager установлен cmd-line tools... Не знаю что делать, может позже поменяю винду...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый способ через командную строку:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

Если будет ругаться что не найдено `%ANDROID_HOME%`, то необходимо добавить его в `PATH`.

---

Второй способ через Android Studio:

Запускаем -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. Ставим галку на `Google Play Licensing Library`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я поменял винду, сейчас всё норм)